# how create a new NSUrlSession (after first session is invalidated)

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, invalidation

As suggested from Apple I use finishandinvalidate method for `NSURLSession` after that my app downloads each file. 
Then the app must have download new update file but I don't reach to create new session.
Method to create session is this:

```
- (NSURLSession *)backgroundSession
{
    NSString* sessionIdentifier=@"com.liuk.pf";
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:sessionIdentifier];

    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                            delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    });
    return session;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem.
I was using this snippet suggested from Apple:

```
- (NSURLSession *)backgroundSession
{
/*
 Using disptach_once here ensures that multiple background sessions with the same identifier are not created in this instance of the application. If you want to support multiple background sessions within a single process, you should create each session with its own identifier.
 */
    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.example.apple-samplecode.SimpleBackgroundTransfer.BackgroundSession"];
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    });
    return session;
}
```

then my nsurlsession was static and created only once.

Now I create nsurlsession in init method of my nsobject

```
self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.my.myapp"];

        _session= [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    }
    return self
```